# Sharepoint Web template

Tags: web-template, web

I have created a web template solution by following Vesa "vesku" Juvonen 's blog(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx).

I have the web template and have created sub sites with it. Now I need to create a web template from this template, which would consist of lists and other items. The publishing feature does not have the save as template option, So I get into the _layouts/savetmpl.aspx to create one or deactivate the publishing feature to create getthe "save as site template option and create one. It creates but does not work properly. I access the site by appending the default.aspx to the newly created sites url and it does not have any features as that of root template. Is there any way to create a template from the existing web template to work correctly. I am a newbie to sharepoint and vesku's blog has been my reference. Any options or views to do it correctly would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well as a work around have created a web part where the sub sites has all the lists of the parent site and made sure it uses the publishing template just as the parent site. Its just a workaround to save the user the trouble of recreating sub sites with same lists as the parent site.
Any other idea or views then please do share.
Thank You.